# Compile time assert in Swift?

Tags: swift, assert, static-assert

Is it possible to concoct a compile time assert in Swift like static_assert in C++? Maybe some way to exploit type constraints on generics to force a compiler break?

Comment: I have no idea how it can be useful. and Swift already can use `where` to constrain generics

Comment: something like #error?

Comment: I only mentioned constraining generics as potential implementation approach, not what I wanted to assert. In my case I was defining a large number of inter-related compile time constants integers that I wanted to validate at compile time. Something I would normally use static_assert for in C++.

Comment: I am not entirely sure that Swift actually has compile time constants. Anyway, a normal `assert` will do almost the same job.

Comment: @Sulthan: No, it won't. There is a huge difference between catching an error at compile time (before you ship) and at runtime when the user finds the bug by crashing (that is, if the assertion is still in place in your release build which usually isn't, so weird stuff might happen instead). So if you can let the compiler catch as many problems as possible that's a Good Thing™.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been accepted into Swift as of version 4.2, here is the [Swift evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0196-diagnostic-directives.md) for the proposal.

Answer (score -7):

If you're talking about a general assert, where the app will crash if a given condition fails, just use: `assert(condition,message)`

For example: `assert(2 == 3,"failing because 2 does not equal 3")`

This is possible in Swift. However, I should note that Apple's design mantra is that an app should never crash, but instead should handle all its errors in a "sophisticated" fashion.

Comment: You're referring to the normal runtime assert. What I'm asking about is a compile time assert like static_assert in C++. This is used for statically verifiable expressions that cause a compiler error when they fail.

Comment: Neil, sorry I didn't really follow -- I haven't used static_assert. The very end of the basics section in the Swift book briefly mentions assertions. I didn't see anything regarding compile time asserts like what you're asking. I don't know if they even support them. Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html